# Error CS0136 A local or parameter named '...' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope

Tags: c#, sql

This is an error message :

> Error  CS0136  A local or parameter named 'cmd' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter  Ayubo_Car_Rental_System D:\Education File\Visual Studio\Ayubo Car Rental"

This is my code:

```
              try
                {
                    Sqlconn.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd = Sqlconn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Rent";

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable DT = new DataTable();

                    SDA.Fill(DT);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;

                    Sqlconn.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception EX)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error" + EX);
                }
```

Comment: Did you find this one when you had your web-search: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0136

Answer (score 2):

The error message informs you that you already defined a variable named "cmd" outside the try block. Therefore, you are not allowed to do "SqlCommand cmd = Sqlconn.CreateCommand();" You have two options to fix this:

- Remove the SQLCommand before the cmd in case you don't need a new variable, but would like to override the existing one. This will work only if the already defined variable has the same type.
- Rename "cmd" to a variable name you didn't use before.

Comment: A third possibility: You don't need to define a new variable with the name "cmd" but you may (possibly intended to)  use the already defined variable.

Comment: Direct them towards leveraging the `using` statement, please, or use the (string,string) constructor of DataAdapter so that making a con/cmd is unnecessary

Comment: @Elec: This is identic to "my" 1st option ;) But anyway, there will be a lot of further options if you want to find some.